# plot selected columns as bar and time series using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 lists and added them to a pandas data frame and want to plot last 3 (range: 1-10) as stacked bar and other 2 (range: 30-100) as time series . Stacked bar as separate plot at bottom and time series above it. Sample data is provided below:

```
           A           B        C      D      E
0        41.62       41.62      0      1      0
1        65.67       33.19      3      0      1
2        46.51       32.47      3      1      0
3        40.91       40.91      0      1      0
4        88.37       32.10      1      1      1
5        46.71       46.71      0      1      0
6        33.24       33.24      1      0      0
7         0.00        0.00      0      0      0
8        46.34       32.57      1      5      0
9        45.41       32.84      1      3      0
10       40.83       40.83      0      1      0
```

Stacked bar is easy to create by adding only 3 lists to data frame but struggling to separate columns, if add all 5 lists to same data frame:

```
pct_list = pd.DataFrame({'C':c,'D':d,'E':e})
# pct_list = pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b,'C':c,'D':d,'E':e})
pct_list.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.ylim([0,10])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Please suggest how to create both plots and control axes limits separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
ax=df.plot.bar(['A','B'],['C','D','E'],stacked=True)
```

To improve the xlabels display  :

```
ax.figure.tight_layout()
plt.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: A and B are a separate time series that I want to have in a subplot. x-axis labels should range from 0-29 but your suggestion is actually using values of A and B as x-axis label